# explain uname -a command on linux? How to find vender's name of OS?

Tags: linux, unix, operating-system, uname

I am facing problem to find output the `Operating system name` and `version` number on `linux` system. I hit a command `uname -a` , but i can't understand the output of this command, can anybody please explain the below output and help me to find the operating system name and version?

```
$ uname -a
Linux ABC007 2.6.32-573.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Aug 10 09:44:54 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I need to find the Vender name of OS, like Intel, Redhat etc. Any command to do so?

Answer (score 7):

from the `man` page:

> DESCRIPTION
>          Print certain system information.  With no OPTION, same as -s.
>
> -a, --all
>                 print all information, in the following order, except omit -p and -i if unknown:
>
> -s, --kernel-name
>                 print the kernel name
>
> -n, --nodename
>                 print the network node hostname
>
> -r, --kernel-release
>                 print the kernel release
>
> -v, --kernel-version
>                 print the kernel version
>
> -m, --machine
>                 print the machine hardware name
>
> -p, --processor
>                 print the processor type or "unknown"
>
> -i, --hardware-platform
>                 print the hardware platform or "unknown"
>
> -o, --operating-system
>                 print the operating system

So, in your case `uname -a` output is:

> Linux ABC007 2.6.32-573.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Aug 10 09:44:54 EDT 
>   2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

- kernel: Linux
- Network node hostname: ABC007
- Kernel release: 2.6.32-573.3.1.el6.x86_64
- Kernel version: #1 SMP Mon Aug 10 09:44:54 EDT 2015
- Machine hardware name: x86_64
- Processor type: x86_64
- Hardware platform: x86_64
- Operating system: GNU/Linux

Comment: is this OS of Intel or Red hat ?

Comment: @GirdharSinghRathore: The information from `uname -a` does not tell you which distribution it is explicitly.  There's a decent chance that the `el6` part, and the sub-version (573.3.1) are in fact unique to one distribution, but you'd have to know how the different distributions identify their versions to interpret that information moderately accurately.

Answer (score 4):

You can use below command to print the only operating system name and version or Release info:

```
lsb_release -a
```

Command Output:(Currently running Ubuntu)

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
Release:        12.04    
Codename:       precise
```

Answer (score 0):

```
man uname
>for finding out os-name
cat/etc/os-relase
```

Comment: Please edit your post rather than adding extra information as comments.  Please try to add more detail to your answers.  Also your cat/etc/os-relase is incorrect.  Please ensure that you have checked your sample statement is correct, posting the output would have proven this.